# Cut ultrasound signal between specific values using Octave

Tags: octave

I have an ultrasound wave (graph axes: Volt vs microsecond) and need to cut the signal/wave between two specific value to further analyze this clipping. My idea is to cut the signal between  0.2 V (y-axis). The wave is sine shaped [as shown in the figure with the desired cutoff points in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF3bQ.png)

In my current code, I'm cutting the signal between 1900 to 4000 ms (x-axis) (`Aa = A(1900:4000);`) and then I want to make the aforementioned clipping and proceed with the code.

Does anyone know how I could do this y-axis clipping?

Thanks!! :)

```
clear
clf
pkg load signal
for k=1:2
  w=1
  filename=strcat("PCB 2.1  (",sprintf("%01d",k),").mat") 
  load(filename)
  Lthisrun=length(A);
  Pico(k,1:Lthisrun)=A;


  Aa = A(1900:4000);



  Ah= abs(hilbert(Aa));

  step=100;
  hold on
i=1;
Ac=0;
      for index=1:step:3601
          Ac(i+1)=Ac(i)+Ah(i);  
          i=i+1
          r(k)=trapz(Ac)
      end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify what’s/where you want clipped/cut?  You currently clip out a section on the time axis, as you say. But then you say you want to cut the signal between two specific taxis values, but only give one value (0.2V).  Ideally, what part of that graph do you want left to analyze after you’re done clipping?  Are you trying to cut out everything below 0.2 volts? (Get rid of the near zero noise?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to cut everything below 0.2 volts and only use data above 0.2 volts. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, you want to just look at values 'above the noise' in your data. Or, in this case, 'clip out' everything below 0.2V.  the easiest way to do this is with logical indexing.  You can take an array and create a sub array eliminating everything that doesn't meet a certain logical condition.  See this example:

```
f = @(x) sin(x)./x;
x = [-100:.1:100];
y = f(x);
plot(x,y);
```

[image: plot of sin(x)/x]

```
figure;
x_trim = x(y>0.2);
y_trim = y(y>0.2);
plot(x_trim, y_trim);
```

[image: plot of sin(x)/x, just point > 0.2]

From your question it looks like you want to do the clipping after applying the horizontal windowing from 1900-4000. (you say that that is in milliseconds, but your image shows the pulse being much sooner than 1900 ms).  In any case,  something like

```
Ab = Aa(Aa > 0.2);
```

will create another array `Ab` that will only contain the portions of Aa with values above 0.2.  You may need to do something similar (see the example) for the horizontal axis if your x-data is not just the element index.

Comment: Thanks so much! That is exactly what I needed.